# WPF command binding: CanExecute parameter

Tags: wpf, binding

Is the parameter passed to the CanExecute method of bound commands the CommandParameter specified in the binding control? If not, where does it come from?

Comment: Yes, it is the `CommandParameter`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `CommandParameter` is sent to both the `CanExecute` and `Execute(d)` events.

Answer (score 2):

Alex Curtis is right:

```
public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
public void Execute(object parameter)
```

Use both the object that was set as `CommandParameter` for the command.

This is also good to know when calling ICommand's `OnCanExecuteChanged(EventArgs e)` because this method won't let you pass any parameter. So CanExecute must use the CommandParameter previously set.